# Why thread function is not called here in TinyThread++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program where I can't use C++11 and I am using TinyThread++ for threading support since it follows the standard C++ API as much as possible. I have extracted a minimal working example from my program, though I am not sure if I have captured the problem exactly. No matter, here is the code:

```
namespace chops {
    template <typename Fun>
    struct my_thread_par {
        Fun f;
    };

    template <typename Fun>
    void my_call(void* args) {
        std::cout << "here2\n";
        my_thread_par<Fun> *par = (my_thread_par<Fun>*) args;
        par->f();
    }


    template <typename Fun>
    struct my_thread {
        my_thread() {
            std::cout << "here1\n";
            Fun f;
            my_thread_par<Fun> par;
            par.f = f;
            tthread::thread t(my_call<Fun>, (void *) &par);
            t.join();
        }
    };

    struct log {
        void operator()() {
            std::cout << "log\n";
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    chops::my_thread<chops::log> t3();
}
```

In TinyThread++, you need to pack your thread arguments into a struct-like thing and pass it as `void *` , as in pthread API. In this minimal example, the line `std::cout << "here2\n";` is not called, which I am thinking due to thread function is not being called. This is strange because I am waiting for thread to join. In fact, debug print `here1` is also not printed which means `my_thread` constructor is not being called either.

In my actual program, I can see that thread runs just fine if I wait for them to join but if I do `t.detach()` instead of joining, It also does not print anything. So with all that in mind, and by the minimal example, what can cause a thread to work fine when I wait for join but can't even enter the thread function when detached?

Note: TinyThread++ is a small library, you can just work with the example yourself. I could not share an online link with wandbox since things are multiple file.

Comment: Are you sure this example compiles? In the `my_thread` constructor, you use `par->f`, but `par` isn't a pointer, nor does it have a custom `operator->`

Comment: It was definitely compiling and running, maybe I changed the code while playing with it. That should be dot operator and I am editing the question as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line

```
chops::my_thread<chops::log> t3();
```

try invoke

```
t3();
```

and you will get `function t3 is undefined` - *boom*, surprise.

You have declared function which doesn't take any arguments and returns `my_thread` object. If you want to create instance of my_thread write:

```
chops::my_thread<chops::log> t3;
```

Comment: But why, shouldn't `chops::my_thread<chops::log> t3();` call the default constructor as well? I did as you said and it works fine but I still don't get why above line does not call the default constructor.

Comment: @meguli Explanation of this issue you have here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse. Try `chops::my_thread<chops::log> t3{};` to instance object.